# Alamofire4 error: "Constant 'fileURL' captured by a closure before being initialized"

Tags: swift3

I have read Alamofire4 migration guide and implemented the following code

```
    let fileURL: URL
    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        return (fileURL, [.createIntermediateDirectories, .removePreviousFile])
    }
```

But I have this error on the 2nd line:

```
 Constant 'fileURL' captured by a closure before being initialized
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I assume you mean this [Alamofire 4.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I solve this?

```
let fileURL: URL = <something returning URL value>
```

Comment: what you did return in fileurl ? i am facing same issue i want to download zip file from url so how can i do it